# What does the placenta consist of?

Tags: zoology

It includes the basal plate, the pool of blood between the chorionic plate and the basal plate and the chorionic plate, what else?

Comment: Why isn't anyone giving an answer

Comment: Possibly because the question seems like it could be easily answered via Google, and because you haven't demonstrated that you've made any effort to answer it yourself yet. Putting it another way, what do you think the answer is? What is blocking you from researching this yourself?

Answer (score 1):

You could’ve easily googled this, but anyway...

Placenta is a composite structure made of embryonic and maternal tissues. 
The placenta is composed of: The chorion, which is the embryonic-derived portion of the placenta. Chorion contains the trophoblast cells (cells that make up the outer cell layer of the blastocyst). finger-like structures called chorionic villi are also present in the placenta. Lastly, the space in the placenta that surrounds the villi and the maternal blood is called the intervillous space.

Source: https://study.com/academy/lesson/the-placenta-and-the-fetus-structure-and-function.html